# Twig_Error_Runtime with symfony2 crud generate

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am following these 2 tutorials from last 2 weeks on different machines like linux and windows.

- http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/08/07/symfony2-jobeet-day-1-starting-up-the-project/
- http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/21/jobeet-tutorial-with-symfony2/

But each time I got stucked at

> { php app/console doctrine:generate:crud }

and I found below error

[Twig_Error_Runtime]
 Key "category" for array with keys "id, type, company, logo, url, position,
  location, description, how_to_apply, token, is_public, is_activated, email
 , expires_at, created_at, updated_at" does not exist in "form/FormType.php.
 twig" at line 29

Comment: do you have any source to it? it seems that you are just trying to access "category" on an object which does not have a getCategory() method..

Comment: by source you mean code? if yes then you can check above link in which author have guided for creating .orm.yml file and with that we create Entity files and after that we run CRUD, you can check on above 2 links. 
Please help!